# LibGDX resize window font drawing

Tags: java, layout, opengl-es, libgdx, font-size

I have problem with font drawing in LibGDX.
I want to be able to resize window and texts will be readable.
Default application orientation is **portrait**, like this:

[image: Portrait Application]

I can **change it before start to landscape** in my application and everything works fine:

[image: Landscape Application]

**But I want to be able to resize application from portrait to landscape. But when I try it (eg. from "landscape" to "portrait" , texts are stretched.**

[image: Resized Application]

My code for render and resize function (it is just code from scratch):

```
public void render () {

    try
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //background draw
        //_spriteBatch.begin();
        //_spriteBatch.draw(background, 0, 0);
        //_spriteBatch.end();

        _spriteBatch.begin();
        //sprite.draw(batch);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        _spriteBatch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
        _spriteBatch.end();


        //content draw
        _spriteBatch.begin();

        if(!_isLandscape)
          _spriteBatch.draw(img, 20, 210, 30, 45);

        //NameDayDOM nameDayDOM = new NameDayDOM();
        NameDaySAX nameDaySAX = new NameDaySAX();
        name = nameDaySAX.getCurrentName(_serviceProvider.getAssetHandleResolver().resolve("namesday.xml").file());
       //II _font.draw(_spriteBatch, "Happy Name Day, dear " + name, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 7.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2.0f);

        if(!_isLandscape) {
            BitmapFont.TextBounds bounds = _font40.getBounds("Happy Name Day");
            _font40.draw(_spriteBatch, "Happy Name Day", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 5.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 120);
            bounds = _font30.getBounds("dear" + name);
            _font30.draw(_spriteBatch, "dear  " + name, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 3.2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("Post picture from this venue");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "Post picture from this venue", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 9.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 4.7f);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("and tell to world,");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "and tell to world,", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 7.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5.5f);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("that you are enjoying your NameDay!");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "that you are enjoying your NameDay!", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 2.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6.5f);
        }else{
            BitmapFont.TextBounds bounds = _font40.getBounds("Happy Name Day");
            _font40.draw(_spriteBatch, "Happy Name Day", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 14.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 1.7f);
            bounds = _font30.getBounds("dear" + name);
            _font30.draw(_spriteBatch, "dear  " + name, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 11.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2.0f);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("Post picture from this venue");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "Post picture from this venue", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 14.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 4.7f);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("and tell to world,");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "and tell to world,", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 11.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5.5f);
            bounds = _font23.getBounds("that you are enjoying your NameDay!");
            _font23.draw(_spriteBatch, "that you are enjoying your NameDay!", (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-bounds.width) / 9.0f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6.5f);
        }
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        _log.error("Exception on render: " + e);
        _serviceProvider.getAppStatusListener().onStateChanged(AppState.Error);
    }
    finally {
        _spriteBatch.end();
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width , int height){
    try {
        System.out.println(width + " " + height);
        if (height > width) {
            _isLandscape = false;
        } else {
            _isLandscape = true;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

What I am doing bad? Why the layout of texts isn't changing after resizing window?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); //<--This.
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

This is because your window changed size, but the OpenGL Viewport didn't. I highly advise you to use an [OrtographicCamera](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html) instead though.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I must use OrtographicCamera. But I am not sure, in what way. Please can you provide some sample? I just need to draw text strings after resizing correctly.